# How to add environment variables to jetty server in java sdk?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I've manually created jetty Server and run my application inside java application.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
    
public void startServer() {
Server server = new Server(0);
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setResourceBase(explodedWar);
webAppContext.setExtraClasspath(getExtraClasspath());
    
            
server.start();
}
```

I want to run war with some javaagent. I've tried to add javaagent option:

```
webAppContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.configuration", "JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:some-javaagent.jar");
```

But seems it doesn't works. How to add environment variables or VM options for war in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Java agents are JVM wide, not WebApp specific.

You'll have to run the entire Jetty server, from the JVM startup with that agent enabled on the Java command line.